# Writing polynomial as a product of elementary symmetric polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-polynomials

Write $x^2y+xy^2+x^2z+xz^2+y^2z+yz^2 $ as a product of elementary symmetric polynomial

I get $E1=x+y+z$, $E2=xy+xz+yz$, $E3=xyz$.
I've tried factoring out E3(xyz) but I can tell that's not right. I know this probably isn't that difficult, think I'm just going about it the wrong way.

Please help!!

Comment: That can't be done. The best you can do is to write your polynomial as a sum of products of elementary symmetric polynomials.

Comment: why do you have only five terms? you are missing $x^2 z$

Comment: @WillJagy You're right, my bad. I've made the edit to include it now. Thanks!

Comment: After your edit, the sum is symmetric and we find easily that $x^2y+xy^2+x^2z+xz^2+y^2z+yz^2 = E_{2}*E_{1} - 3 E_3$

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Thanks for the answer but I still can't manipulate it to... (xy+xz+yz)(x+y+z)-3(xyz). Could you show me the workings please?

Comment: Please see the solution of @Hagen von Eitzen who explained it 14 minutes after my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a unique way to write $x^2y+xy^2+x^2z+xz^2+y^2z+yz^2$ as a polynomial in $E_1,E_2,E_3$. Note that $x^2y$ could nicely be obtained by expanding the product $(x+\ldots)(xy+\ldots)$, and indeed after expanding $E_1E_2$, we obtain the desired expression - plus $3xyz$. Hence
$$x^2y+xy^2+x^2z+xz^2+y^2z+yz^2=E_1E_2-3E_3.$$

Comment: Thanks @Hagen. Should of noticedthat and expanded E1.E2 straight away. Appreciate the help!